# CI File Upload file size exceed even after taking several measures

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-3

In my Codeigniter based code, I have taken the following measures:

**MultiPHP INI Editor in Cpanel**

```
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = Off
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 128M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 128M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

**.htaccess in Home Directory**

```
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 20000
   php_value max_input_time 20000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 2G
   php_value post_max_size 2G
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 20000
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2G
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 20000
   php_value max_input_time 20000
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 2G
   php_value post_max_size 2G
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 20000
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2G
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

**First lines in Controller and Model:**

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "100000000");
ini_set("max_allowed_packet ", "2G");
ini_set("max_execution_time ", "20000");
ini_set('max_input_time','20000');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');
set_time_limit(0);
```

**$config before file upload**

```
$config=array(
    'upload_path'=>$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/uploads/rpt/",
    'allowed_types'=>"rpt",
    'overwrite'  => TRUE,
    'max_size' => '100000000',
    'file_name' =>$filename
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if($this->upload->do_upload('rpt1'))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    return "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$this->upload->display_errors()."</div>";
}
```

**Still I am getting the below message on uploading file greater than 2 MB size:**

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP
>   configuration file.

What else is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
```

After modifying `php.ini` file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

If you can't change your `php.ini`, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in `php.ini` will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to `ini_set`.

OR

Even you can set in `.htaccess` file of project

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Gupta PLease have a look at the info shared above. htaccess part is already mentioned there.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but things didnt work out. I have also added the content of MultiPHP INI Editor which I forgot to share ealier.

Comment: Once try to replace post_max_size 2G with post_max_size 1800M and try again.Even you getting error then let me know.

Comment: Even change  upload_max_filesize 2G to upload_max_filesize 1800M.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I opened the WHM to edit php INI settings. making changes there corrected the issue.